# QGraphicsView and QSplitter: collapsing and unfolding area does not restore image

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5, qgraphicsview

I am trying to create a basic program that has two side-by-side panels: one with image, and one with text. I am using splitter to be able to resize both areas up to the point of completely collapsing one of them. This works fine with `QTextEdit`.

However, when I collapse the `QGraphicsView` (with additional code that fixes division by zero error), neither the image reappears, nor the background I set as default. I find myself lost at what I should do to make the image and background reappear.

This is the image after loading the image – moving the splitter will also resize the image (this is also the desired final state):
[image: Before collapsing the image]

This is how it looks after I completely collapse the image and move the splitter back to the center:
[image: After collapsing the image]

Debug indicates that `QPixMap` still has the data, but they are not displayed properly. I tried adding `self.scene().update()`, but that still didn't influence the outcome.

Code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class ImageViewer(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ImageViewer, self).__init__(parent)
        self._empty = True
        self._scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        self._photo = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem()
        self._scene.addItem(self._photo)
        self.setScene(self._scene)

        self.setTransformationAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setResizeAnchor(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.AnchorUnderMouse)
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setBackgroundBrush(QtGui.QBrush(QtGui.QColor(30, 30, 30)))
        self.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)

    def setPhoto(self, pixmap=None):
        if pixmap and not pixmap.isNull():
            self._empty = False
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.ScrollHandDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(pixmap)
            self.fitInView()
        else:
            self._empty = True
            self.setDragMode(QtWidgets.QGraphicsView.NoDrag)
            self._photo.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap())

    def fitInView(self, scale=True):
        if self._empty:
            return

        rect = QtCore.QRectF(self._photo.pixmap().rect())
        if not rect.isNull():
            self.setSceneRect(rect)
            viewrect = self.viewport().rect()
            scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
            if scenerect.width() == 0 or scenerect.height() == 0:
                return
            factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(), viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())
            self.scale(factor, factor)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        if not self._empty:
            self.fitInView()

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Panel Editor")
        self.setGeometry(250, 150, 1600, 1200)

        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.splitter = QtWidgets.QSplitter(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.viewer = ImageViewer()
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.viewer)

        self.textEditor = QtWidgets.QTextEdit()
        self.splitter.addWidget(self.textEditor)

        # Set the initial sizes of the splitter's panels to divide the space equally
        self.splitter.setSizes([800, 800])

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.splitter)

        self.createMenu()

    def createMenu(self):
        self.menuBar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar()
        self.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        
        fileMenu = self.menuBar.addMenu('&File')
        openAction = QtWidgets.QAction('&Open', self)
        openAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openAction.setStatusTip('Open image')
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.openImage)
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)

    def openImage(self):
        imagePath, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Image", "", "Image Files (*.png *.jpg *.bmp)")
        if imagePath:
            self.viewer.setPhoto(QtGui.QPixmap(imagePath))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just checking the scenerect, but you're not ensuring that the viewport size is actually valid. The result is that you could end up with a null dimension (width and/or height) of the viewport that will cause the `viewrect/scenerect` fractions equal to zero, and that will become the factor.

Since the *current* factor is also used for `self.transform().mapRect(rect)`, restoring the size of the view will have no effect because the current transform uses the 0 factor above.

The solution is then to only apply the transform as long as the viewport rectangle is valid (*both* height and width > 0), which can be done by checking those values or the helper functions [`isValid()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrect.html#isEmpty) or [`isNull()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qrect.html#isNull).

Alternatively, just set the scale as long as `factor > 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [musicamante's excellent solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78156366/3918419), I modified `fitInView` to get it to work with the below code:

```
def fitInView(self, scale=True):
    print("fitInView called.")
    if self._empty:
        print("No photo to fit in view.")
        return

    rect = QtCore.QRectF(self._photo.pixmap().rect())
    if not rect.isNull():
        self.setSceneRect(rect)
        viewrect = self.viewport().rect()

        # Ensure the viewrect is valid before proceeding
        if not viewrect.isValid():
            print("Viewport rect is invalid; cannot fitInView.")
            return

        scenerect = self.transform().mapRect(rect)
        if scenerect.width() > 0 and scenerect.height() > 0:
            factor = min(viewrect.width() / scenerect.width(), viewrect.height() / scenerect.height())

            # Apply scaling only if factor is greater than 0
            if factor > 0:
                self.scale(factor, factor)
                print(f"Photo fitted with factor: {factor}")
            else:
                print("Scaling factor is zero or negative; cannot fitInView.")
        else:
            print("Scene rect is zero sized; cannot fitInView.")
    else:
        print("Pixmap rect is null; cannot fitInView.")
```